# Why the tableHeaderView got removed when I added that to another subView and replace the tableHeaderView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

This is the full code of what I want to do (only 2 lines)

```
[self.headerViewofWholeTable addSubview:self.delegate.tableView.tableHeaderView];
self.delegate.tableView.tableHeaderView= self.headerViewofWholeTable;
```

Things doesn't work, so I started adding print information

```
[self.headerViewofWholeTable addSubview:self.delegate.tableView.tableHeaderView];
PO(self.headerViewofWholeTable.subviews);
self.delegate.tableView.tableHeaderView= self.headerViewofWholeTable;
PO(self.headerViewofWholeTable.subviews);
```

Simple 4 line of codes :D

Result:

```
 self.headerViewofWholeTable.subviews: (
        "<UILabel: 0x8bf9770; frame = (50 15; 250 21); text = 'Pull Down to Refresh'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bf97e0>>",
        "<UILabel: 0x8b63aa0; frame = (50 35; 257 20); text = 'last updated'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b63b10>>",
        "<UIView: 0x8b63b80; frame = (20 11; 22 54); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bf6c40>>",
        "<UIImageView: 0x8be9ca0; frame = (0 0; 320 10); autoresize = LM+RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be9ce0>> - shading-top-Table.png"
    )
 self.headerViewofWholeTable.subviews: (
        "<UILabel: 0x8bf9770; frame = (50 15; 250 21); text = 'Pull Down to Refresh'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bf97e0>>",
        "<UILabel: 0x8b63aa0; frame = (50 35; 257 20); text = 'last updated'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b63b10>>",
        "<UIView: 0x8b63b80; frame = (20 11; 22 54); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8bf6c40>>"
    )
```

So you see,

that     `self.delegate.tableView.tableHeaderView= self.headerViewofWholeTable`; remove the view that's pointed to by self.delegate.tableView.tableHeaderView. However, the view

```
"<UIImageView: 0x8be9ca0; frame = (0 0; 320 10); autoresize = LM+RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8be9ce0>> - shading-top-Table.png"
```

should not go away because it's retained by self.headerViewofWholeTable

So can anyone explain what happened?

I can easily circumvent the problem, but I want to know more of what's actually going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the implementation of the `UITableView setTableHeaderView` method (which you call in the second line) assumes that the current header view is still a subview of the table. So when you try to assign a new header view, the table view first removes the current header from its superview (not knowing it has already been moved to your other view). The table view isn't expecting that its header view has been moved to a new view. So it ends up removing the header view from your `headerViewofWholeTable` view.

Comment: So the tableView actively remove the headerView from it's superview by calling removeFromSuperview?

Comment: That's not what I said. When you try to assign a new table header to the table, the table first removes the current table header from the table. This is done by calling `removeFromSuperview` on the current table header. The table simply assumes the current header is still attached to the table. It doesn't first check to see if the current header has actually been moved elsewhere. Of course I'm guessing here. I have no access to the `UITableView` source code. But the evidence, and my experience, leads me to this likely conclusion.

Comment: actually that's my guess too. I'll wait for other guesses.